# Retina Nvidia Control Panel Settings for Gaming

Tags: macbook-pro, graphics, games

I've had a retina MBP for about a year now. I want to start using it for gaming. I have read that I need to change the Nvidia Panel Settings. Does anyone know specifics on what I should change to optimize gaming performance? thanks

FYI this is for Battlefield 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my settings for BF3 - I also have a rMBP (15"). You can modify these settings under **Manage 3D Settings** in the NVIDIA Control Panel:

[image: NVIDIA BF3 Settings]

I leave everything else to default, except I also turn off *Anisotropic Filtering*.

For the above settings to take effect, the following setting must also be set under **Adjust Image Settings with Preview**:

[image: Use the advanced 3D image settings]

---

Also, don't forget about BF3's settings. I use [Realmware BF3 Settings Editor](http://bf3.realmware.co.uk/settings-editor/) to edit settings out of the game.

[image: BF3 Settings]